# MongoDB connection not working in YII2

Tags: php, yii2

I'm new bee to yii2 and php. I am creating a project using YII2 and mongodb but giving an error {"response":"failed","status_code":500,"message":"\"db\" refers to a yii\mongodb\Connection component. yii\db\Connection is expected."}

my component file is

```
 return [
    'db' => require (__DIR__ . '/_mongodb.php'),
    'urlManager' => require (__DIR__ . '/_urlRules.php'),
    'request' => require (__DIR__ . '/_request.php'),   
    'log' => require (__DIR__ . '/_log.php'),
    'response' => require (__DIR__ . '/_response.php'),
    'user' => require (__DIR__ . '/_user.php'),
    'cache' => require (__DIR__ . '/_cache.php'),
    'mailer' => require (__DIR__ . '/_mail.php'),
    'languageSelector' => require (__DIR__ . '/_languageSelector.php'),
    'i18n' => require (__DIR__ . '/_i18n.php'),    
    'assetManager' => [
        'class' => 'app\components\asset\AssetManager',
        'resource' => [
            'path' => 'resources' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
            'tempPath' => 'temp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
            'thumbnailPath' => 'thumbs' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        ]
    ],
    'storageFactory' => [
        'class' => 'app\components\storage\StorageFactory',
        'local' => [
            'class' => 'app\components\storage\FileStorage',
            'connector' => require (__DIR__ . '/_localStorage.php')
        ],
        'network' => [
            'class' => 'app\components\storage\FileStorage',
            'connector' => require (__DIR__ . '/_localStorage.php')
        ]
    ]
]?>
```

_mongodb.php file

```
return [
    'class' => 'yii\mongodb\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/genie'
];
```

i tried in google nothing found

Answer (score 0):

Several classes of the Yii framework use the `db` component and expect it to be of type `yii\db\Connection`, this is why you get the error.

Make sure to check the [docs on the MongoDb Connection class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mongodb-connection.html), here you can see how to properly initialize the mongodb component. Configure a new property like this:

`mongodb => require(__DIR__ . '/mongodb.php')`

Now you can use it by referencing to it with `Yii::$app->mongodb`

Furthermore you just leave out the `db` component if you don't need to work with a relational database.